# Est-il correct d'employer « de base » ? Si oui, dans quel(s) cas ?

Tags: expressions

J'entends souvent des personnes dire « de base ». Il y a peu de temps en France, beaucoup l'utilisait, comme si c'était une mode.

Par exemple:

> « De base il n'est pas assez fort »

Pour dire "à l'origine", "d'abord", "déjà"... En réalité c'est assez difficile de définir véritablement son sens dans ce cas là.

Mais il me semble que l'utilisation de l'expression est incorrecte, d'ailleurs je ne l'avais jamais entendu auparavant.

A mon sens une utilisation plus juste serait :

> « J'ai acquis les connaissances de bases dans le domaine »

Qu'en dites-vous?

Answer (score 7):

"De base" est beaucoup utilisé dans le français parlé un peu familier. Son sens est effet quelque chose comme "Déjà", ou "en fait". Cependant l'utilisation de "de base" avec ce sens dans le français écrit n'est pas recommandé car non formel.

> J'ai acquis les connaissances de bases dans le domaine

est la bonne utilisation de "de base" pour le français écrit, ici le sens est "primaire", ou "essentielles".